Snowflake taking different execution plan for different date passed
I have a Snowflake SQL query which has the WHERE snippet is like the following, where i try to generate WHERE clause with the columns dynamically in the equality condition:
Select C1,C2,..... from
(Select ..... from "VC_DLY_FEE_ISS" WHERE "VC_DLY_FEE_ISS"."BUS_DT" BETWEEN CAST('2024-11-10' AS DATE) AND CAST('2024-11-10' AS DATE) ) as T0
WHERE "T0"."C1" = (CASE '2024-11-10' WHEN '1900-01-01'THEN "T0"."C50"                                            ELSE "T0"."C1" END)      
The execution plan differs for different date being passed based on the underlying custom view. It is also that the above query always follows the ELSE within the CASE statement as per the logic, and unsure if the plan getting changed in below has got anything to do with the CASE statement.
Good plan:
For few dates, it takes the below plan route for JOIN operation in the underlying view, which works good because 2 columns from both the tables are joined.
Equality Join Condition in the plan is -
(​DLY_FEE​.​BUS_DT = TRAN_DLY​.​BUS_DT​)​ AND ​(​DLY_FEE​.​RLTD_TRAN_ID = TRAN_DLY​.​TRAN_ID​)​
Bad plan
For few different dates, it takes the below plan route for JOIN operation in the underlying view, which works bad, because one of the column is substituted for the date from calling query, and this results in cartesian join between both tables, since 2 columns from both tables are not exactly joined.
Equality Join Condition in the plan is -
​(​DLY_FEE​.​BUS_DT = '2024-12-01'​)​ AND ​(​DLY_FEE​.​RLTD_TRAN_ID = TRAN_DLY​.​TRAN_ID​)​
Note - The query also consistently follows the same plan for the same date, if being queried again. Say 2024-12-01 always follows the Plan B, but the 2024-11-21 always follows Plan A. So, unsure if the route changes based on evaluating some of the data in the underlying table.
Please provide what could be some of the reason the equality condition in the JOIN operation in the plan is getting changed for certain dates?
